# Asynchronous ActionCreator in React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm pretty new in React-Redux. Was working on an application. The thing is that I faced some issues with asynchronous execution of Redux actionCreator, may be.

Below is my component. Say, I want to call an actionCreator from `componentDidMount()` or from an onclick event listener.

```
class Dashboard extends PureComponent {

     componentDidMount() {

          this.props.getProductsAndPackages();

          let something = [];
          something = this.props.products;

     }
....................................
}
```

Or , the function `this.props.getProductsAndPackages();` can be an onClick event handler that does the same thing, context is the same. I'll ask my question after first explaining my code.

At the lower side of my Dashboard container:

```
Dashboard.propTypes = {
getProductsAndPackages: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
products: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
.......................

 };

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
         .....................
         products: state.products.products,
         ...................
    };  
};


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getProductsAndPackages: () => dispatch(getProductsAndPackagesActionCreator()),
    };
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard));
```

My actionCreator goes like:

```
export const getProductsAndPackagesActionCreator = () => {

return (dispatch) => {

    dispatch(productsIsLoading(true));

    let url = 'xyz';

    if(!!localStorage.getItem('_token')) {
        const local_token = localStorage.getItem('_token');
        const fullToken = 'Bearer '.concat(local_token);

        axios.get(url, {headers: {Authorization: fullToken}})
            .then(response => {
                dispatch(productsIsLoading(false));
                if (response.data.statusCode === 200) {
                    dispatch(productsFetched(true));
                    dispatch(products(response.data.data));
                } else {
                    dispatch(productsFetched(false));
                    dispatch(productsErrors(response.data.message));
                }

            })
            .catch(error => {


            });

    } else {

        axios.get(url)
            .then(response => {
                dispatch(productsIsLoading(false));
                if (response.data.statusCode === 200) {
                    dispatch(productsFetched(true));
                    dispatch(products(response.data.data));
                } else {
                    dispatch(productsFetched(false));
                    dispatch(productsErrors(response.data.message));
                }

            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                dispatch(productsIsLoading(false));
                dispatch(productsErrors(error.message));

            });

    }


};
};
```

Now, I want my `getProductsAndPackagesActionCreator()` to return a Promise or anything that would allow my `something` variable to get the actual data returned from the server. Right now, by the time I'm getting actual data, the line `something=this.props.products` has already been executed and I get back the initialValue that was set for `products`.

I know, whenever I'll receive the populated `products`, component will re-render, but that does not help my decision making.

I'm using `redux-thunk`, by the way.

What should I do now ? Sorry for such a long post.

Comment: Hi you could pass you're response's data to your action's `payload` and then update your store. Once you do that you won't need any `cont something` since it will be available as `props` in your component from `mapStateToProps`

Comment: I've already done it. As you can see, I'm just assigning <code>this.props.products<code> value to <code>something</code>.
The problem however is, by the time the axios call ends, <code>something=this.props.products</code> has already been executed. and <code>something</code> is being assigned the <code>initialState</code> value primarily that has been set from my reducer.
I want to ensure that, my <code>something</code> variable is assigned with only the populated array received from axios get request.

Comment: Btw: probably you have mistake: 
                `dispatch(productsIsLoading(false));` should be in finally block, because catch is not always invoked.

Comment: Originally I have that code within catch block. But I omitted it just for brevity.

Comment: Ok, about your problem, you made request in componentDidMount, so you component is rendered before call request, so first component is rendersed with initialState, after componentDidMount is invoked and then rerender component.

Comment: That's the problem I want solution of. In the componentDidMount(), I have called actionCreator and the value should be populated already if I could do something like async/await. And I don't want my data in render methods, but in the componentDidMount(), right after the function call.

Comment: Maybe move this section to componentDidUpdate
<code>
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.products !== prevProps.products) {
    let something = [];
         something = this.props.products;
  }
}
</code>
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: Let's say, I want to have a check in componentDidMount() like:

    if(something) {
      //do something
    }

Though I do have products, I'll get back an empty array for the first time. I think, you've got my point.

Comment: Plabon I understand but IMO you shouldn't use didMount because you made async call and you have to wait one lifecycle more, that's I propose use didUpdate according react lifecycles: http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/ :)

Comment: I'm not being able to make you understand, mate. My point is not calling it from didMount or didUpdate or any eventHandler. From wherever you call that getProductsAndPackages() method, you won't get the value in the immediate next line. That's why I'm confused about how to implement a Promise or async/await.

Comment: The first quesiton is: Why on earth do you want this? You are using React and Redux so use the power of your selector! Just dispatch the action whenever you want and then let the selector pass it as prop for your component... Then your Render will do the rest, and meanwhile it is async calling, show some loading feedback in your render. 
That is the pattern you should follow, explain us please why you want to break this pattern. Because the problem is there...

Answer (score 1):

Actually I wanted `getProductsAndPackagesActionCreator()` to return a promise, which was pretty straightforward, to be honest. I figured out that if you just `return` the `axios.get()` or `axios.post()`, it will return a promise. So, the modified code looked like below:

```
export const getProductsAndPackagesActionCreator = () => {

  return (dispatch) => {

    dispatch(productsIsLoading(true));

    let url = 'xyz';

    if(!!localStorage.getItem('_token')) {

        return axios.get(url, {headers: {Authorization: fullToken}})
            .then(response => {
               ............
               ............
            })
            .catch(error => {


            });

    } else {

        return axios.get(url)
            .then(response => {
                ...........
                ...........
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
  };
};
```

And then, I could do something like below in `componentDidMount()` or on any onClick event:

```
this.props.getProductsAndPackages().then(() => {
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        clicked_product: this.props.product_by_id
    }, () => {

       //do other stuffs

    });
});
```

Feel free to let me know if there's any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are close to getting what you want. First of all, you should understand that redux actions and react actions like setState are asynchronous, so you have to apply your logic keeping this in mind. I'm going to explain what i think in some points:

1. You have called the action creator in the correct place **componentDidMount**, also you can call this action in any onClick if you want.
2. As soon as you dispatch the action you are changing your redux state setting loading true I suppose. So now you can access this property in your render function, so you can render a Loader until your api call finishes.
3. When your ajax function finishes, with an error or not, I suppose you are setting loading to false and updating your products data, so you can render now your loaded products in your dashboard.

Are you sure that you have to compare your empty products array with the received data? Maybe you can check in your render function `if (!this.props.products.length) return null`, when you load your page you will see a loader function and later your dashboard with the products.

If you really need to compare previous products with received products **componentDidUpdate** is your method. In this method, you can access your previous props and compare with actual props, be careful comparing arrays, remember [] === [] is false. Maybe you can compare the length, something like

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
   if(prevProps.products.length !=== this.props.products.lenth){          
       doSomething()
   }
}
```

Just to say that componentDidUpdate is executed after render, so be careful with your code to no-execute extra renderings.

Hope it helps, if you dont understand anyting just tell me :)